# Ajuda em Portugol (se e senao)

Tags: portugol

Desejo que o usuário ao digitar "0" tenha o programa encerrado no mesmo momento,pois 0 é um número inválido,porém não consigo,o Portugol me retorna mil erros,eis o código:

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro base,altura,area
        escreva("\nDigite a base:")
        leia(base)
        escreva("\nDigite a altura:")
        leia(altura)
        se((base == 0) ou (altura ==0)){
            escreva("\nNúmero inválido")
            pare
        } senao se((base >0) e (altura >0)){
        area = base*altura
        escreva("\n A área do retângulo é:",area)           
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: A comparação dentro do se, tem diferença se for um inteiro ou se for uma string? Tipo 0 é diferente de "0".

Comment: Você quer ficar em um loop sem fim calculando enquanto o usuário não digitar um número inválido ou executar apenas uma vez e caso o cara digite 0 (zero) você informe o número incorreto e não calcule?

Comment: Executar apenas uma vez,e caso o usuario digite 0 (zero) apareça "Opçao inválida,tente novamente" e encerrar o programa.Mas caso tu queira me mostrar os 2 jeitos,ficaria muito agradecido,porém o que eu citei já está de bom tamanho.

Comment: Edward Ramos,tem diferença sim,eu declarei como inteiro tanto a variável base como altura,portanto só aceitará números.

Answer (score 2):

Torricelli, para manter o programa em execução até o usuário digitar o número inválido, o código pode ficar da seguinte forma:

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro base,altura,area
        logico continua = verdadeiro

        enquanto(continua) {
            escreva("\nDigite a base:")
            leia(base)
            escreva("\nDigite a altura:")
            leia(altura)

            se ((base == 0) ou (altura ==0)) {
                escreva("\nNúmero inválido")
                continua = falso
            } senao se ((base >0) e (altura >0)) {
                area = base*altura
                escreva("\n A área do retângulo é:",area)           
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Caso não precise manter o loop, o código quase não muda, pois qualquer um dos números inválidos já não permite a execução do cálculo:

```
programa
{

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro base,altura,area

        escreva("\nDigite a base:")
        leia(base)
        escreva("\nDigite a altura:")
        leia(altura)

        se ((base == 0) ou (altura ==0)) {
            escreva("\nNúmero inválido")
        } senao se ((base >0) e (altura >0)) {
            area = base*altura
            escreva("\n A área do retângulo é:",area)           
        }
    }
}
```

E para sair assim que o usuário digite o primeiro número inválido, pode ficar da seguinte forma, criando uma função simples que valida o número digitado:

```
programa
{

    funcao logico validaValorDigitado(inteiro valor) {
        se (valor == 0) {
            escreva("\nNúmero inválido")
            retorne falso
        } senao {
            retorne verdadeiro
        }
    }

    funcao inicio()
    {
        inteiro base,altura,area

        escreva("\nDigite a base:")
        leia(base)

        se (nao validaValorDigitado(base)) {
            retorne
        }

        escreva("\nDigite a altura:")
        leia(altura)

        se (nao validaValorDigitado(base)) {
            retorne
        }

        area = base*altura
        escreva("\n A área do retângulo é:",area)
    }
}
```

Todos os códigos foram baseados no que você postou, espero que te ajude!

Comment: Funcionou,muito obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

no lugar de pare escreva o comando **interrompa** na linha abaixo do comando  escreva("\nNúmero inválido").